# Client authentication vs. Password authentication in presence of TPM on the client device

Tags: authentication, passwords, x509certificate, client-certificates, tpm

With the goal of better understanding the pros and cons of using certificate-based client authentication vs. password-based authentication I have searched previous posts here and read [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3605/certificate-based-authentication-vs-username-and-password-authentication).

Yet I’d like to consider a specific scenario where 1) clients are applications deployed on devices and using unguessable passwords (anyway available on the client device if taken over by an attacker); 2) certificates are signed by a private CA owned by the organization deploying the server as well as the client applications; 3) clients do not (need to) perform a logout; 4) TPM is available on the device and 5) an attacker can get physical access to a device holding the certificate/password.

The way I understand it, the key of a client certificate can be hardware-secured on the client TPM, thereby making it impossible to reuse the same certificate in a different device.
Still, I’m not clear if an attacker with physical access to the device would get a chance to read the secret as it is handed over to the application by the TPM.

Wondering if the same could be applied to passwords.

I did not consider revocation in my context because the server could as easily revoke a password if needed without putting a PKI in place.

Does the presence of a TPM makes one option over the other preferred? Are there other aspects that make one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 0):

> Still, I’m not clear if an attacker with physical access to the device would get a chance to read the secret as it is handed over to the application by the TPM.

the key point of TPM (like smart cards, HSMs) is key privacy. It never is exposed to an application. Instead, TPM exposes interfaces to perform cryptographic operations using the key, but not the access to key material. Instead of taking the key and doing something (sign or encrypt data) and thus accessing key material, you ask TPM to perform requested operation (sign or encrypt data) and get the result, but never touch key material.

In addition, passwords are often cached somewhere in memory by applications (due to unreleased handles, or active references for example), TPM performs cryptographic operations inside the chip and never leaves it.

This is where TPM beats passwords. If you have TPM, go with it.

Comment: Then I have to make sure that the result of the encryption done by the TPM/HSM is not subject to a reply attack. Which means that the authentication protocol must include a server-provided challenge. And this rules (Basic) Password Authentication out. But I could use any secure protocol that provides a challenge, so not necessarily TLS with client certificates.

Comment: Transport security is very different question, which isn't related to client certificates, passwords or TPM. It is TLS that provides data privacy on a wire.